# @empty giving "Undefined variable: __empty_0"

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

I am currently trying to set up my blade layout with **laravel 5.4** but I seem to be having issues with the @empty statement while using it [with loops](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/blade#loops)

The code I am trying to use is:

```
@foreach ($notifications as $notification)
    <li data-for='{{ $notification->lobbyid }}'>
        @if ($notification->approved == 1) 
             <div class='notification-text'><strong>{{ $notification->sentBy }}</strong> wants access to your lobby:  \"{{$notification->title}}\".</div>
             <div class='notification-actions' id='HI' data-for='{{ $notification->lobbyid }}' data-userid='{{ $notification->userid }}'><span data-type='{ \"as\": \"requesting\", \"action\": 1 }'>Accept</span><span data-type='{ \"as\": \"invited\", \"action\": 0 }'>Deny</span></div> 
        @else 
            <div class='notification-text'><strong>{{ $notification->sentBy }}</strong> invites you to join his lobby: \"{{$notification->title}}\".</div>
            <div class='notification-actions' id='HI' data-for='{{ $notification->lobbyid }}' data-userid='{{ $notification->userid }}'><span data-type='{ \"as\": \"invited\", \"action\": 1 }'>Accept</span><span data-type='{ \"as\": \"invited\", \"action\": 0 }'>Deny</span></div>      
        @endif
     </li>
@empty
    <li>No Notifications</li>
@endforelse
```

And I get the following error:

Undefined variable: __empty_0

When used separately it works great:

```
@endforeach

@empty($notifications)
    <li>No Notifications</li>
@endempty
```

But I would like the cleaner syntax like on the laravel documentation.

Comment: You're missing `foreach` with `forelse`.

Answer (score 4):

```
@foreach ($notifications as $notification)
```

it should be @forelse not @foreach

Comment: Wow, I did not even notice that! Thank you!